# How to select a max row for each group in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group

I want select countries with maximum value of 'Value' for a 'grpid'.  Also already selected 'Country' should not be considered for other 'grpid' while checking the maximum. ( ie Country or grpid should not be repeated in the result )

**[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fbf76/1)**

***Result:***

```
Country    grpid        Value           Row_number

US        49707        604456458         1
GB        5086         497654945         4 
CA        909          353500201         10
JP        231          198291290         15
```

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dc8f52e2-a03d-4183-bf35-dc2ab14f2632/how-to-select-a-max-row-for-each-group-in-sql?forum=transactsql

Comment: in result  Country or grpid should not be repeated... in your result 'GB' and 'US' is  repeating.

  1) select countries with maximum value of 'Value' for a 'grpid'

  2) 'grpid' & country should not be repeated.

  3)  we need to take next maximum  value if 'grpid'  not  there a for  highest value.

Comment: Why didn't you include **`grpid '50147'`**

Answer (score 7):

try this query instead,

```
  WITH OrderedOrders AS
  (
     SELECT country,grpid,value,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY country ORDER BY   country,value DESC) AS 'RowNumber' 
     FROM test1
  ) 
 select * from  OrderedOrders
 where RowNumber =1
```

Comment: Worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 6):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/56293/3/0)

```
;with cte as 
(
  select 
      country,
      max(value) as MaxVal,
      min(row_number) as MinRow
  from test1
  group by Country
)
select 
  c.country,
  t.grpid,
  c.MaxVal,
  c.MinRow
from cte c
join test1 t
  on t.country = c.country 
  and t.value = c.MaxVal
  and t.row_number = c.MinRow
order by country, grpid
```

Comment: simple self-join by showing how to use `with` keyword is useful and link renewed. +1

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try out this query

```
select 
    country,
    value,
    grpid,
    count(*) 
from test1 
group by  
    country,
    value,
    grpid 
order by 
    country,
    value desc
```

Comment: thanks, this wont work output       Result:

Country grpid Value Row_number

US 49707 604456458 1

GB 5086 497654945 4

CA 909 353500201 10

JP 231 198291290 15
  in result  Country or grpid should not be repeated... in your result 'GB' and 'US' is  repeating.

  1) select countries with maximum value of 'Value' for a 'grpid'

  2) 'grpid' & country should not be repeated.

  3)  we need to take next maximum  value if 'grpid'  not  there a for  highest value.

Comment: in result  Country or grpid should not be repeated... in your result 'GB' and 'US' is  repeating.

  1) select countries with maximum value of 'Value' for a 'grpid'

  2) 'grpid' & country should not be repeated.

  3)  we need to take next maximum  value if 'grpid'  not  there a for  highest value.

Comment: can you pls remove the country from the group by and select list and try?